# Hadoop Distributed Cache don't work

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, distributed-cache

I'm new with Hadoop. I'm using Hadoop 0.22.
In the Driver I'used this code:

```
    Job job = Job.getInstance(configuration);
    ...
    job.addArchiveToClassPath(new Path(JAR_DIR);
    ...
```

In the Map class what code I have to use to add the jar in the local classpath?

More details

I have a job that need in the map and reduce phases htmlunit.jar.I add this jar to classpath with the code above, but when I submit the job, I have a ClassNotFoundException at line that I use htmlunit references.If the code above it's ok, and the DistributedCache add automatically the jar in the tasktrackers classpath, what could be the problem?
I also have to use the option -libjars htmlunit.jar when I submit the job? I have to use another hadoop component?

Comment: Try this link: [link] http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/filecache/DistributedCache.html . It provides example of how to use disturbed cache. Also, can you elaborate the question?

Comment: What is your question? It's not possible to help you if you don't give any more details than just "don't work".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.

Once you add a jar to the job classpath what you're saying is

> "include this in the class path of the map and reduce jobs"

So long as your mappers and reducers extend from the Mapper and Reducer base classes then it will 'just work'.

Worth noting, you should probably instead use addFileToClassPath for each individual Jar you need.

An alternative (we do this) is to create one single jar containing your source and your dependencies.

Build your code jar as usual, then create a subdirectory in the jar called 'lib', and add all of your dependency jars in here. Then your entire job is self contained and you don't need to worry about adding other jars to the distributed cache.

So for example you'd have a jar with the following contents:

```
/com/example/Something.class
/com/example/SomethingElse.class
/lib/dependency.jar
/lib/dependency2.jar
```

(a jar is just a zip file, so you can use regular zip creation utilities to build it)

For various reasons this also performs better than adding the .class files of your dependency to the jar directly.